# How to add arrow at left and right to move slide ? Currently I have to press shift and scroll to move it

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Here I am just mapping videosdata and displaying its thumbnail into flex slider

**Row.js**

```
return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <div className="row">
            <h2>Top Rated</h2>
            <div className="row_thumbnails">
              {videos.map((item) => (
                <img
                  onClick={() => handleClick(item.id)}
                  key={item.id}
                  className="row_thumbnail rowLarge"
                  src={item.thumbnail}
                  alt={item.title}
                />
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
```

**Row.css**

```
.row {
  color: white;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.row_thumbnails {
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  padding: 20px;
}   
.row_thumbnails::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
.row_thumbnail {
  object-fit: contain;
  width: 246px;
  height: 138px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  transition: transform 450ms;
}   
.rowLarge {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
}    
.row_thumbnail:hover {
  transform: scale(1.08);
}    
.row6 {
  margin-bottom: 10rem;
}
```

**Any simple way to add something like arrow that will help to move the slider without
Shift scrolling horizontally.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are lots of solutions, but I doubt they are "simple" or "quick"
You would have to track the position of an element in the window, then changing the offset of an img container to a value of a width of an img.

`TLDR: you don't need to implement your own img carousel, its not easy and quick solution. just use some library`

Nevertheless, you just can use an external library that will do the logic for you. You only have to provide an array of data to it))

Smth like this:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-multi-carousel

Comment: i tried with react slick slider and multi carousel but the space between images are not controllable. I can share my output if u want to see